# Determine if lagrange theorem allows you to conclude that H must be a cyclic group

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let (G,.) be a group and H a proper subgroup of G

n is the order of G

a) n=15

b) n=18

c) n=49

d) n=37

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:  If you take powers of any given element, then you necessarily generate a subgroup with order equal to the order of that element.  The elements of this subgroup are $\{e, g, g^2, g^3, ..., g^{k-1}\}$, where $g$ has order $k$ in this instance.

Remember that a group $G$ of order $n$ is cyclic $\iff$ there exists an element $g \in G$ of order $n$.

Comment: I have no clue where to start my professor has not done any like this could you please show me how to do at least just one. :(

Comment: I'll do a couple examples.  Consider a group $G$ of order $41$.  Select any element $a \in G$.  Start taking powers of $a$:  $\{a, a^2, a^3, ..., e\}$.  As stated in my post, this is a subgroup of $G$.  Now apply Lagrange's theorem.  What could the order of this subgroup be?  Well, it must be a divisor of $41$.  But notice that $41$ is prime.  Thus, to be a divisor of $41$, the subgroup would have to have order $41$.  Therefore, $a$ has order $41$, and we conclude that $G$ is cyclic.

Comment: However, what if the order of $G$ was $15$?  Well, we again consider a subgroup generated by some element $a$ as above.  What is the order of this subgroup?  Well, by Lagrange's theorem, it could be $3$, $5$, or $15$.  Therefore, we cannot conclude that $G$ is cyclic using just Lagrange's theorem because it's possible that every subgroup generated by an element has order $<15$.